# Why won't my animation repeat properly?

Tags: css, animation

Here it is on JS fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/VR7AN/

I have made a simple animation with the basic principles of this guide: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/02/fullscreen-background-image-slideshow-with-css3/

The animation runs perfectly the first time, but when it loops it turns grey and only cycles through some of the images. I can't figure out why the loop would work but not the same as the first time.

Here's my css:

```
#fadethru > img { 
 position: absolute;
 color: transparent;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 0;
 display: block;
 -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 4.5s linear infinite 0s;
 -moz-animation: imageAnimation 4.5s linear infinite 0s;
 -o-animation: imageAnimation 4.5s linear infinite 0s;
 -ms-animation: imageAnimation 4.5s linear infinite 0s;
 animation: imageAnimation 4.5s linear infinite 0s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
}

#fadethru > img:nth-child(1)  {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 0.5s;
 -o-animation-delay: 0.5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 0.5s;
 animation-delay: 0.5s; 
}

#fadethru > img:nth-child(2) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
 -o-animation-delay: 1s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 1s;
 animation-delay: 1s; 
}

#fadethru > img:nth-child(3) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 1.5s;
 -o-animation-delay: 1.5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 1.5s;
 animation-delay: 1.5s; 
}

#fadethru > img:nth-child(4) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
 -o-animation-delay: 2s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 2s;
 animation-delay: 2s; 
}

#fadethru > img:nth-child(5) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 2.5s;
 -o-animation-delay: 2.5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
 animation-delay: 2.5s; 
}

#fadethru > img:nth-child(6) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
 -o-animation-delay: 3s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
 animation-delay: 3s; 
}

#fadethru > img:nth-child(7) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 3.5s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 3.5s;
 -o-animation-delay: 3.5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 3.5s;
 animation-delay: 3.5s; 
}

#fadethru > img:nth-child(8) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
 -o-animation-delay: 4s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 4s;
 animation-delay: 4s; 
}

#fadethru > img:nth-child(9) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 4.5s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 4.5s;
 -o-animation-delay: 4.5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 4.5s;
 animation-delay: 4.5s; 
}



@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
  15% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
  50% { opacity: 1 }
  75% { opacity: 0 }
  100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
  15% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
  50% { opacity: 1 }
  75% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@-o-keyframes imageAnimation {
   0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    15% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    50% { opacity: 1 }
    75% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    15% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    50% { opacity: 1 }
    75% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    15% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    50% { opacity: 1; }
    75% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div id="fadethru">
        <img src="img/redjewel.png" id="red" alt="red jewel">
        <img src="img/orangejewel.png" id="orange" alt="orange jewel">
        <img src="img/yellowjewel.png" id="yellow" alt="yellow jewel">
        <img src="img/grassjewel.png" id="grass" alt="green jewel">
        <img src="img/greenjewel.png" id="green" alt="turquois jewel">
        <img src="img/bluejewel.png" id="blue" alt="blue jewel">
        <img src="img/indigojewel.png" id="indigo" alt="indigo jewel">
        <img src="img/purplejewel.png" id="purple" alt="purple jewel">
        <img src="img/pinkjewel.png" id="pink" alt="pink jewel">
    </div>
```

Comment: Please transfer your demo to jsfiddle or some other 3rd party site. You shouldn't be linking to URLs that are going to go away in the future.

Comment: Seems to be working fine in latest chrome and safari. What browser are you using?

Comment: Added it to jsfiddle. I'm looking at it on firefox and chrome. Its hard to tell but the animation on the second repeat is only looping 4 of the images instead of all 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to display each item only for the portion of the time of the total loop it takes up.  So 9 displays / 100 percent = 11.11 percent of total loop time per element.

You have the elements displaying from 15-50% of the loop, so when it starts to repeat, some elements are covering others, but that doesn't work properly, so through that error you are seeing grey.

I did mine as 0-14%, lazily, and also only for chrome (which I use) so I didn't have to type all that code!  But it should fix your issue:

```
#fadethru > img {
    opacity:0;
     position:absolute;
        top:0; left:0;
 -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 4.5s linear infinite 0s;
}
```

and

```
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
  8% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
  9% { opacity: 1 }
  14% { opacity: 0 }
  100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

Comment: I also removed some of the img styling... such as color:transparent;  its hard to test those things across browsers, so I just kept it simple here.